# Moq Assert an abstract method is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I'm writing a unit test for my Abstract class using AutoFixture, this is a representation of what I'm trying to do:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual void DoSomethingCool()
    {
        OnDoingSomethingCool();
    }

    protected abstract void OnDoingSomethingCool();
}
```

My unit test would look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

    var sut = fixture.Create<Base>();

    // How to assert that the OnDoingSomethingCool method was called
    sut.Invoking(x => x.DoSomethingCool())
        .ShouldNotThrow();
}
```

So how do I assert that the protected abstract method was actually called in the `DoSomethingCool` method??

If it were an object from an injected dependency, I would be able to setup a mock using `Moq` and assert that the method was called, but since the method is an abstract method **inside my Subject Under Test**, how do I assert the method was called?

Comment: You are using AutoFixture as an [Auto-mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/), however this is really a question about Moq.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bunch that can be said about this:

1. It seems like you might be either testing too much, or giving too much control to other implementations.

   - (Too much control) Usually, if you want to force a method to be called from another method in your `abstract class` you do not make it `public virtual`. By doing this, you have given the future implementations the ability to change this behavior. In fact, if you remove the `virtual`, then you can get the test you want (see below). I did provide a way to keep the `virtual`, but again...not recommended. This is not recommended since your SUT is your mock...which doesn't feel right.
   - (Testing too much) You should only care about basic behavior, not implementation details, lest your tests become too brittle. I am assuming that there is more than just the call to the `OnDoingSomethingCool` method, otherwise you should just make that your main method. If the primary behavior is this call (and there is more than just this call), then I do cover that in my `NotRecommended` method below.
2. You should not test the abstract class directly. You should probably use what Roy Osherove calls the **Abstract Test Class Pattern** in [The Art of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/). This makes it so that all implementations test your behavior. You can then pass in a dependency. If you would like that example or even a simplified example off the **Abstract Test Class Pattern**, let me know

/

```
using Moq.Protected;

...

public void NotRecommended_ProbablyTestingTooMuch_BrittleTestBelow
{
    //If you MUST keep DoSomethingCool virtual
    //var baseMock = new Mock<Base>{CallBase = true};
    var baseMock = new Mock<Base>();
    baseMock.Protected().Setup("OnDoingSomethingCool");

    baseMock.Object.DoSomethingCool();

    baseMock.Protected().Verify("OnDoingSomethingCool", Times.AtLeastOnce());
}
```